# firefox don't dispaying images in css (content, url)

Tags: html, css

I write responsive page. In desktop, table and mobile must to be images with different extensions. If I embed images in **html** *img src="...."*, all display fine. If I embed images in **css** *content: url*, images don`t display in firefox browser. And I need embed it only in **css**, because as you decrease the screen images will be loaded another. Thanks.

```
<div id="nav_image">
           <div id="images">
            <div class="div_images"><a href="#"><img src="" class="images" id="img1"></a></div>
            <div class="div_images"><a href="#"><img src="" class="images" id="img2"></a></div>
            <div class="div_images"><a href="#"><img src="" class="images" id="img3"></a></div>
            <div class="div_images"><a href="#"><img src="" class="images" id="img4"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

#nav_image #img1{
    content: url(http://images.apple.com/v/home/cm/images/promos/iphone_6s_large.jpg);
}

#nav_image #img2{
    content: url(http://images.apple.com/v/home/cm/images/promos/apps_for_earth_large.jpg);
}

#nav_image #img3{
    content: url(http://images.apple.com/v/home/cm/images/promos/macbook_large.jpg);
}

#nav_image #img4{
    content: url(http://images.apple.com/v/home/cm/images/promos/accessories_large.jpg);
}
```

Comment: show your code, cc, html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `image` is `inline` element. So you can set `display` to `block` or `inline-block`.

[JSBIN.](http://jsbin.com/huyejatabu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thanks. All doing.